# Encryption through C# & Decryption through SQL Server 2008 for ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, encryption-symmetric

On my front end, I have following functions:

method to encrypt:

```
  public static string Encrypt(string strToEncrypt)
        {

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
            byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetEncryptionKey));
            objHashMD5 = null;
            objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
            objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
            byteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));


        }
```

method to decrypt:

```
public static string Decrypt(string strEncrypted)
        {

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
            byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetEncryptionKey));
            objHashMD5 = null;
            objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
            objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
            byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(strEncrypted);
            string strDecrypted = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(objDESCrypto.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
            objDESCrypto = null;
            return strDecrypted;

        }
```

and the GetEncryptionKey function is

```
   private static string GetEncryptionKey
    {
        get { return "#$&*(^($%"; }
    }
```

EDIT:
Now here's my problem:
so am asked to Encrypt the User's password using Encrypt function written on the front end (during registration or password change) and Decrypt the encrypted password(from front end) through a Stored Procedure( during login).
How can I do so?

Comment: why would you want to save the decrypted values into your database - somewhat defeats the purpose... BTW: putting the key into the client-app in this way is not a good idea as well (and DES... well - better use AES)

Comment: Carsten..sorry if you got confused..please see the Edit portion in the question. I need to decrypt those encrypted values(saved in db) through an SP

Comment: no - I'm not confused this is exactly what I thought - BUT: normaly you use a cryptographic hashfunction (for example SHA) to hash the password on the client and compare this to the stored hash on the server (adding IV for security) - you should never store the users plaintext-password nor know it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: you can plug in .net assemblies into SqlServer to run .net functions - here is a [Tutorial for .net 2.0 / SqlServer2005](http://www.sitepoint.com/host-net-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: yeah..though it is bit of lengthy and not that neat but anyways serves my purpose.